# Install and enable 'Real AES' module: Dependency with Defuse PHP-encryption library

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I downloaded the real_aes-8.x-2.2.zip file from the [Real AES](https://www.drupal.org/project/real_aes) project page, unzipped and copied it to contrib module folder (/var/www/html/modules/contrib).

While trying to enable this module using `drush en real_aes`, I get below error:

> Module real_aes doesn't meet the requirements to be enabled.                                                        [error]
> Please install the Defuse PHP-encryption library via Composer. See README.txt (Currently using Defuse PHP-Encryption[error]
> library version Not Installed)

So now I ran the command `composer require defuse/php-encryption` to install Defuse PHP-encryption. I could see that it is downloaded to the location /var/www/html/vendor.

After this, even though the Defuse PHP-encryption is downloaded, if I try to enable the Real AES module using Drush command and also tried Drupal module interface, it still throws the above error.

- Drupal version: 8.6.5
- PHP Version : 7.0.32
- Drush version: 8.1.18

Any help appreciated resolving this issue.

Comment: So your site is managed with Composer? Then you `composer require drupal/real_aes` and it will also get you the library. Otherwise ensure you download the correct version of the library `composer require defuse/php-encryption:^2.2`. Flush cache and retry. Next thing: your Drush version is incompatible with Drupal 8, fix that. Next thing: Your Drupal version is out of date, fix that, too.

Comment: You need to execute `composer require defuse/php-encryption` in the correct directory, in order to let Drupal find the library. Then, since you used Composer to add the library, you could as well add the module with `composer require drupal/real_aes` as @leymannx said.

Answer (score 0):

Founded solution:

1. Download Ludwig - https://www.drupal.org/project/ludwig
2. Install module and go to admin/reports/packages - https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/ludwig/installation-and-usage
3. Install automatically or add manually to folders:

- modules/address/lib/doctrine-collections/1.8.0
- modules/address/lib/doctrine-deprecations/v1.0.0
- modules/address/lib/commerceguys-addressing/v1.4.2
- modules/commerce/lib/commerceguys-intl/v2.0.1

4. Next clear the cache - admin/config/development/performance

Now u can install all modules :)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The OP was not trying to install the Commerce module, so this answer does not really answer the question.